# BeautifulSoup find all table empty

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a very simple table from a NOAA website: https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/PRECIP_HLY_sample_ascii.dat

The table is a ".dat" file and the site appears to be in html. When I use BeautifulSoup to read the content, I can see the content just fine. However, when I then search for the table with "find_all" or "find," I get nothing, i.e., [].

Here is my initial code:

```
page = requests.get('https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/PRECIP_HLY_sample_ascii.dat')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') #'html5lib' #'html.parser' 'lxml'
table = soup.find_all('table')
```

When I type soup, I get the following:
[image]

However, when I try to get the info into a table, it comes up blank

```
table
>> []
```

I have tried the following variations:

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/PRECIP_HLY_sample_ascii.dat').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html5lib') #'' #''

table = soup.findAll('table') 
table = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"line-gutter-backdrop"}) 
table = soup.find_all(True)
```

However, table still comes up blank.

I found this question that appears to be similar:[Cannot find table using Python BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072879/cannot-find-table-using-python-beautifulsoup)

But my table is not in javascript (as far as I know). It is just text.

I am very new to data scraping and really have no idea why this simple example is not working. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There was another answer to this question yesterday, but now it is gone. Could you please repost it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the `table` tag because there is not, you have to find the `pre` tag.

You can try this snippet, it will get the text inside the table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib

url = 'https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/samples/PRECIP_HLY_sample_ascii.dat'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

page_soup = soup(html,'lxml')
table = page_soup.find('p')
print(table.text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
STATION           STATION_NAME                                       ELEVATION  LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  DATE           HPCP     Measurement Flag Quality Flag 
----------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- -------- ---------------- ------------ 
COOP:310301       ASHEVILLE NC US                                    682.1      35.5954    -82.5568   20100101 00:00    99999                ]              
COOP:310301       ASHEVILLE NC US                                    682.1      35.5954    -82.5568   20100101 01:00        0                g              
COOP:310301       ASHEVILLE NC US                                    682.1      35.5954    -82.5568   20100102 06:00        1
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get this into a pandas dataframe using this method?

Comment: I think panda is used to get the data from a table tag, so I don't think it is possible here. But I'm not an expert of panda :-)